# Request for member "nameField" in something not a struct or union :error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

My Error message:

> Request for member "nameField" in something not a struct or union

My Error code:

```
NSString *msg = nil;
if (nameField.text.length > 0)
    msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Relax, %@, all is good".nameField.text];
else
    msg = @"Relax, all is good";
```

Comment: try with if([nameField.text length] >0)

Comment: Thx dude . But got **Expected ":" before "]" token** error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code line

```
msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
       @"You can breathe easy,%@, EveryThing went ok". nameField.text];
```

try this

```
msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
       @"You can breathe easy,%@, EveryThing went ok", nameField.text];
                                                     ^
```

change in the line is you have used. instead of comma here -> :@"...",

check if this helps

Answer (score 0):

you have a dot (.) where you should have a comma after ok"  in the initWithFormat